# How to close a Salesforce lightning tab like below by use javascript?

Tags: lightning, tab, javascript-controller

I create a button link to lightning component,How to close a Salesforce lightning tab like below by use javascript ?

[image]

Comment: Assuming this lightning component is linked to a quick action, you can use the `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` to close the component.

Comment: Think you so much!

Comment: @Anamadeya It seems your comment solved the issue, please add your comment as answer(With some more details maybe) so that this question can be closed.